# Fill data and click on button on Chrome browser after opening URL

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

I want to open a URL via Chrome to fill in data and hit a submit button, using Excel VBA.

I wrote the command to open the URL.

How do I key in the data and submit the form?

My code:

```vb
Sub OpenHyperlinkInChrome()
    Dim chromeFileLocation As String
    Dim hyperlink As String
    hyperlink = "<URL OVER HERE>"
    chromeFileLocation = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
    Shell (chromeFileLocation & "-url " & hyperlink)
  
    driver.FindElementByName("trackingId").Value = "123"
    driver.FindElementByID("epm-submit-button-announce").Click
End Sub
```

I get a syntax error on `driver.FindElementByName`.

My field HTML code:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Example: BLUE_SHOES_08. This information is for your tracking purposes." name="trackingId" class="a-input-text a-span12">
```

The button HTML code reads as

```html
<span id="epm-submit-button-announce" class="a-button-text a-text-center" aria-hidden="true">
        Submit
</span>
```

How can I fill the form and submit?

Comment: You have a comma before `Click` - That should be a period. Fix that first and see if you still have problems.

Comment: The code has several syntax errors and typos, i.e. it appears to have too many `"` but at the same time there are missing `"`. Regarding the specific syntax error. `driver.FindElementByName("trackingId).Value = "123"` apparently there is a missing `"`after `trackingId`. There aren't enough details to know if `trackingId` is a placeholder used instead of the actual value or a variable.

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected the code and i'm getting a "Run-time error '424': Object Required.

Comment: I've looked at the code for the field and it shows as


"   <div class="a-column a-span12">
                                
                                
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Example: BLUE_SHOES_08. This information is for your tracking purposes." name="trackingId" class="a-input-text a-span12"/>
                                
                                
                            </div>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the "driver" object without defining it or even declaring it.
From the code it looks like you are trying to use Selenium, have you installed Selenium?
After you install Selenium your code should look like this:

```
Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
driver.start "chrome"
driver.Get "<URL OVER HERE>"
driver.FindElementByName("trackingId").SendKeys ("123")
driver.FindElementByID("epm-submit-button-announce").Click
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't work for me because this code opens up a new Chrome browser and the URL requires me to login with an OTP. However if i open my a tab in an existing Chrome window, I'm not required to log in. Currently only the shell command lets me open chrome in an existing tab. Any way VBA can open new chrome tab in existing window?

Comment: So you can open the initial login through the app and then provide it with the OPT so that it enters it in the appropriate place, then navigate to the page you need, it will be the same session.

Comment: But the OTP would change every time, there is no way to automate the OTP right?

Comment: No, you can't automate the OTP but you can instruct your program to stop and ask the user for the OTP, and the rest of the process will be automatic